# How to call Java methods in React Native before startReactApplication has been called

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

In our Android app, I initialize the React Native JS code as soon as possible, because I have some JS code running in the background, even when no React Native views are currently visible. I do this by calling `ReactInstanceManager#createReactContextInBackground()`.

This works, and the JS code gets initialized, but it appears I cannot call any Java methods annotated with `@ReactMethod` until I have actually opened a React Native view that calls `ReactRootView#startReactApplication()`. If I attempt to call any native methods before that, nothing happens, but it seems the calls get added to a queue and then eventually get picked up when the React view opens.

It appears the same thing goes for timers set with `setTimeout()`. They just don't get called when no view is open yet. So it seems the JS gets evaluated, but then the JS engine isn't "running" yet.

How can I make sure the engine is properly running before opening any React views?

Answer (score 0):

Let your first RN View call a @ReactMethod that will set a flag in Java. Have your Java code not execute anything until the flag is set.